# Said tags in Sentence detection

Tags: english, nlp, parsing, sentences, methodology

I am trying to apply NLP to fiction but I don't know how split dialog into sentences. Specifically how to split said tags.
ex.

```
"Awake? How long have been asleep?" asked teenagers at the same time.
```

do I split it like this:

```
"Awake?
How long have been asleep?"
asked teenagers at the same time.
```

or like this:

```
"Awake?
How long have been asleep?" asked teenagers at the same time.
```

or was it already one sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it should be one sentence, but it could also depend on your use case. For example, if you are extracting sentences for the purpose of translation, I think the example you provided should be one sentence.

I wrote a sentence segmenter and tried to find all of the "edge cases" like the example you provided. I then tested all of the popular tools against these edge cases. If you would like to read more about it please check the [README here](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter).

You can also give your example a try in my [tool here](https://www.tm-town.com/natural-language-processing) (there is a browser-based version part way down the page that lets you enter some text) and you'll see it segments it as one sentence.

Answer (score 1):

From the question, it is not clear which language you are using or how you *want* the sentence to be split.

You're looking for a sentence detector, though. If you're using Python, you can use NLTK's `sent_detector` module. By default, it will break up your sentence as:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
>>> txt = '"Awake? How long have been asleep?" asked teenagers at the same time.'
>>> sent_detector.tokenize(txt)
['"Awake?', 'How long have been asleep?', '" asked teenagers at the same time.']
```

If the placement of the quotation marks is important, you can do:

```
>>> sent_detector.tokenize(txt.strip(), realign_boundaries=True)
['"Awake?', 'How long have been asleep?"', 'asked teenagers at the same time.']
```

You can also train a model, using [punkt](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html). In this case, you would feed it examples split up the way you like, and it would learn the pattern.